# Windows phone 8 - Sending Mail in background

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to send mail in background that is without prompting any user action if user has some email account sync in phone?? I believe EmailComposeTask only shows up a screen that requires user action to send the mail. What I need is to send the mail in background without any overhead to user. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't send an email from the user's email account without his approval.

What you can do is use your own server and php script which you can then call from the app to send the email for you, like it's done for [error reporting services](http://bjorn.kuiper.nu/2011/10/02/wp7-littlewatson-extended-error-reporting-to-http-endpoint/).